# How do I merge two string sets in Java but only if they have common elements?

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I'm new to Java and I'm trying (and - apparently- failing) to combine two string sets if they have common elements:

```
CommonElements = Set1;
CommonElements.retainAll(Set2);
System.out.println("common elements of"+Set1+"and"+Set2+":"+CommonElements);
if (CommonElements.size()!=0) {
    Set1.addAll(Set2);
    System.out.println("both sets"+Set1);
}
```

Now, I am applying this same thing though I now have an ArrayList of sets:

```
for (i=0; i<myList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j<myList.size()-i; j++) {
        Set<String> Set1 = myList.get(i);
        System.out.println("Set1"+Set1);
        Set<String> Set2 = myList.get(i+j);
        System.out.println("Set2"+Set2);
        Set<String> commonElements = myList.get(i);
        commonElements.retainAll(Set2);
        System.out.println("Common elements of"+i+"and"+(i+j)+":"+Set3);
        if (commonElements.size()!=0) {
            Set1.addAll(Set2);
            myList.set(i, Set1);
            System.out.println("both sets"+Set1);
        }
        System.out.println(myList.get(i));
```

But System.out.println(myList.get(i)) results in:

if the two sets don't have anything in common: 
Set1 becomes empty, myList.get(i) returns [].

if the two sets do have something in common:
Set1 becomes Set2, so List entry number i takes the value of List entry number i+j.

Comment: That's because the `retainAll` you call on `myList.get(i)` modifies the list. You realise variable assignment to an `Object` doesn't make a copy unless you tell it to?

Comment: Are you trying for a union ( both sets added together ) or intersection ( only elements present in both )

Comment: @Richard: I'm aiming for a union, but I first have to check if there is an intersection because I don't want to merge the sets if they don't have at least one element in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little brute force but...

```
public Set<String> mergeSetsIfAnyOverlap( Set<String> s1, Set<String> s2 ) {
    Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<String>( s1 ) ;   // copy s3
    s3.retainAll( s1 ) ;                           // keep only things in s3 (aka s1 ) that exist in s2
    if( !s3.isEmpty() ) {                          // any common items ... ?
        s3.addAll( s1 ) ;                          // ... yes than merge 
    } else {
        s3.clear() ;                                // otherwise empty s3
    }
return s3 ;
}
```

Comment: sorry... that code provides neither intersection nor union... just copy of `s1`...

Answer (score 0):

1. when you assign `Set1` to `commonElements` you do not make a copy of Set1.
   CommonElements is just another reference to the same Set1. So,

`commonElements.retainAll(Set2);`

leaves only common elements between Set1 and Set2 **in Set1**

2. `Set` in opposite to `List` holds unique objects then:

Now `Set1` has only common objects (i.e. `Set2` has them as well)

And finally `Set1.addAll(Set2);` put remaining objects from `Set2` to `Set1`

After all `Set1` holds exact the same objects as `Set2`.

---

Instead of `Set<String> commonElements = myList.get(i);`

do this:

`Set<String> commonElements = new HashSet<String>();
 commonElements.addAll(myList.get(i));`

Then you will get a UNIQUE UNION at the end.

BTW: in Java there is a standard naming convention to do not name variables Capitalized. Capitalized names are for Types - I mean use `set1` instead of `Set1` as you did properly for `commonElements`.